# Redirect modules

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-6

How can I get a module to redirect if a user doesn't have the correct permissions to view it instead of getting the usual "Access denied. You are not authorized to access this page." message?

Comment: Are you talking about path's defined in hook_menu for a single module. Is it one you have made or is it downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a module you are writing yourself use the goto function of Drupal

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto

If you are not writing it yourself then it's a bit tougher, you can set the error redirects with Drupal and some modules however for a specific module I think you might have to go in and patch it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much anything you wanna do to modify drupal stock behaviour can be handled via [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Error](http://drupal.org/project/customerror) provides the ability to easily customize 403 and 404 error messages. With that, you could use `drupal_goto()` to automatically redirect users, or `drupal_get_destination()` to build a login link that will return the user to the page they attempted to view.

For more general, login-specific functionality, you might check out [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan).

The source code for both modules will also include useful examples of how to approach this problem space if you do not want the overhead or external dependency of a module.